# NodeJS can be workable for AMP and Facebook free basic

Tags: node.js, amp-html, freebasic

I'd like to know NodeJS with jabe can be feasible to implement for AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) & Facebook Free Basic? Regarding Facebook & AMP documentation, javascript is not allowed to use in but I'm trying to use NodeJS with jade template.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side tools are more-or-less irrelevant to your ability to produce client side code which conforms to AMP or Facebook Free Basic.

The ban on JS refers to *client* side JS dependancies.